# Why Hyperledger Fabric’s performance is so bad in our deployment benchmark?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We use Hyperledger Fabric and Composer to build a system with a channel and 3 peers (8GB, 8CPU) but we faced 2 problems like below:

Performance is very low: 10 tps. Is it the limit of the composer or our fault in implementation?

Size is very large, it's more than 20 times compare to SQL Server. With 1000 records in SQL we've used 40MB but with Hyperledger system as above (3 peer) is 700MB (I think if it's linear the size of Hyperledger should be = 40*4 = 160MB). Is this size is normal or our fault? What's the best practices in size optimization?

Thanks in advances

Answer (score 1):

> Performance is very low: 10 tps. Is it the limit of the composer or
>   our fault in implementation?

I don't know about composer but it's definitely not the limit of Fabric. More data about your deployment would be helpful.

> Size is very large, it's more than 20 times compare to SQL Server.
>   With 1000 records in SQL we've used 40MB but with Hyperledger system
>   as above (3 peer) is 700MB (I think if it's linear the size of
>   Hyperledger should be = 40*4 = 160MB).

A transaction with a single endorsement weighs about 3K. 
1000*3K is about 3MB... something here is off ;) 
How many blocks and transactions do you have?

Comment: Hi @yacovm, thanks for your reply, i provide the link about our deployment model: https://photos.app.goo.gl/H4VyEOZhWEveK5LA3
. Could you have email I can sent more about the detail? Thanks

Comment: Hi @yacovm, how to know or mesure exactly the size of transaction/block be store in Hyperledger. At present my way is: get totalsize of Linux after add transaction - total size of Linux before add transaction. It's seem not right way?

Comment: the "deployment model" you provided here doesn't really say anything special about your environment....

I suggest you ask around at the rocket chat channels especially in the ledger channel

Comment: Thanks @yacovm, I'll try this channel

Answer (score 1):

I conducted some similar testing. I took an existing microservice and replaced the MySql, Redis, and Cassandra parts with API calls to a business network built with Hyperledger Composer. The storage capacity for the original microservice was 750 times more efficient than CouchDB under Fabric. You can read all about this experiment in this article on [Evaluating Hyperledger Composer](https://www.infoq.com/articles/evaluating-hyperledger-composer).

Comment: Hi @Glenn, Thanks for your evaluating. We've optimize storage size by switch from json object -> array.

Comment: Is that with a Composer app or are you writing directly for Fabric? Composer is supposed to make it easier to develop for Fabric but perhaps less efficiently?